# What/Who are these?

Tags: riddle

From higher plane do I see,
One side yellow streams of rays do I see,
One side red streams of rays do I see,
The speed of rays I can feel!!!

Can you guess what do I see?

Hint : Is it something given by modern technology?

**Big Spoiler**:

> Can it be related to cars?

Comment: IMHO, you gave that spoiler too soon. You could’ve waited for a day or two so that more user get a chance to try out your puzzle before the big giveaway.

Comment: oops. my bad. new to puzzling :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You see

> a highway, with headlights in one direction and taillights in the other. You're close enough to feel wind from the traffic.

Comment: I would add that the narrator is probably rot13(fgnaqvat ba n oevqtr bire gur uvtujnl), thus explaining the 'From higher plane do I see' line too...

Comment: exactly..... ....

Answer (score 7):

My guess:

> Flag of North Macedonia

*From higher plane do I see,*

> The flag is hoisted

*One side yellow streams of rays do I see, 

One side red streams of rays do I see,*

> The flag contains red and yellow rays

*The speed of rays I can feel!!!*

> The flag is waving

Either that or you could be a

> Bird flying through the sunset high in the sky

Comment: This is a great alternative answer which I never thought of!!!  I should probably edit the question to Who/What are these?

Answer (score 5):

My (second, based on the @msh210 answer) guess would be:

> <s>A red light filter reflecting and refracting sunlight.
>
>  The filter reflects some of the sun light which appears yellow.
>
>  It also refracts the light but blocks all apart from the red light.
>
>  The rays also heat up the filter (it can "feel the speed of rays")</s>
>
>  Traffic speed/enforcement cameras
>  They see the headlights(yellow)/taillights(red) and they measure the speed of the cars.

Comment: When you mentioned filter you are very close to what I thought of!!! Edited the question to put one more hint which might help